# Proper way to start activity that uses camera

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-camera

I've found some opensource document scanner app, first (default) "DocumentScannerActivity" of this app is a camera for capturing images of documents for further processing. Works good, without any error.

Then I've add my own (new) "MainActivity" as default with button inside, with **onclick listener** that opens "DocumentScannerActivity":

```
        scanActivityBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DocumentScannerActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

This code opens "DocumentScannerActivity", but after pressing on "Capture image" application crashes with **error**:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                                           at az.deep.archiverabitabank.DocumentScannerActivity.saveDocument(DocumentScannerActivity.java:1042)
                                                                           at az.deep.archiverabitabank.DocumentScannerActivity.saveDocument(DocumentScannerActivity.java:1129)
                                                                           at az.deep.archiverabitabank.ImageProcessor.processPicture(ImageProcessor.java:161)
                                                                           at az.deep.archiverabitabank.ImageProcessor.handleMessage(ImageProcessor.java:91)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172)
                                                                           at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

Here is the problematic part of code (app tries to save captured image to storage) in **DocumentScannerActivity**:

```
    Uri fileUri = null;
    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE")) {
        fileUri = ((Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT));
        Log.d(TAG, "intent uri: " + fileUri.toString());  //LINE 1042, where error occurs
        try {
            fileName = File.createTempFile("onsFile", ".jpg", this.getCacheDir()).getPath();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        isIntent = true;
    }
```

Here is the related cut from **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />
...
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DocumentScannerActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_document_scanner"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

What I'm doing wrong, how to prevent this error?

Comment: You should post DocumentScannerActivity code or look at line 1042 and debug using break points to figure out why its null

Comment: I've updated my question, please check. Problem is with URI, but I haven't any idea, why it's works without my "MainActivity". Looks like there is issue with writing to storage.

Comment: i think you should use a FileProvider https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html

Comment: Are you sure? I just want to remind you, that if DocumentScannerActivity is default activity, then everything works fine.

Comment: so you are saying it works if its just `DocumentScannerActivity`. I am not sure it would work with just that. it should crash even then. can you name the open source app so that i can test??

Comment: of course — https://github.com/Aniruddha-Tapas/Document-Scanner

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167479/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-deeplay).